# Minimum grid width in Foundation 4?

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, css

Quick question for Foundation 4 SCSS users: Is there a setting in the _config.scss file for Foundation 4 to set minimum width of the grid? I've looked but haven't seen anything. Or do I just have to do it manually in my own styles? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `foundation_and_overides.scss` file there are the following options you can modify:

```
// Grid Variables

$row-width: 70em;
$column-gutter: 1.875em;
$total-columns: 12;
```